# Entity Framework creating a database which system user doesn't have access too

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

I am logged on to windows 8 with my  microsoft account. The computer sees me as BAGGINS\Max (machinename/user) as expected.

I have an application which uses Entity Framework code first to generate the database. However when the database is being accessed with the code I am getting an error saying "BAGGINS\Max" doesn't not have permission to access the database.

I have gone into sql server and BAGGINS\Max has full permission on the sql server instance but no login for that account for the database created by sql server.

I have never had this issue before but then the last time I did it I was on windows 7. Does anyone know what the reason behind this is and possibly a work around?
Cheers!

**Update 1**

I have created other project and have a friend running the same code on his windows 7 computer. Both work. This to mean tells me that I have some wierd thing with windows 8 using live authentication and sql server but I still can't find a solution.l

**Update 2**

I have created a new user in sql server (express 2012) with full administrator rights and used that in the connection string. I am still getting the same error though. Actually that user can't even login to sql server!

Answer (score 1):

I did have a related issue when i upgraded from windows 7 to Win 8 and i had to grant the user account Read/Write access to folder where the database files were.